# Type cast inside lambda expression in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, casting

I'm using Spring Boot under Java 8 and I'm trying to perform a type cast inside a lambda expression, but can't get it to work after a lot of research and try/error.

Suppose I have a list like this:

```
List<Foo> list;
```

that is filled in a step of a batch process, and because of datasource restrictions, the class Foo needs to be declared like this (with all its members as String):

```
class Foo {

    private String id;
    private String quantity;

    public String getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuantity {
      return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
      this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Once the list is loaded, I need to do some grouping and summing based on id, given that the quantity String represents a decimal number.

The following code gives me an error because *summingDouble* is expecting a Double, not a String:

```
Map<String, Double> grouping = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getId, Collectors.summingDouble(Foo::getQuantity)));
```

I managed it to fix the error by adding an extra function to Foo class, like this:

```
public Double getQuantityAsDouble() {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(quantity) ? new Double(0) : Double.valueOf(quantity);
}
```

and doing the call this way:

```
Map<String, Double> grouping = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getId, Collectors.summingDouble(Foo::getQuantityAsDouble)));
```

but it seems a poor solution to me.

Is there any way to direct cast *Foo::getQuantity* from String to Double inside *Collectors.summingDouble()* without the need to add bloat functions to the original bean?

Thanks!

Comment: A `String` is not a `Double, so casting is not possible. Using `Double.valueOf` to do the conversion is a good solution.

Comment: Your private method is in fact a very good solution. It encapsulates the default value (in case the string doesn't represent a number) and the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't do implicit conversion from String to Double, which is what your code is implying.

You need an explicit conversion, which can be accomplished with with a conversion in the stream:

```
Map<String, Double> grouping = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getId,
            Collectors.summingDouble(foo -> Double.parseDouble(foo.getQuantity()))));
```

(or use Double.valueOf if those semantics are more appropriate)

**EDITED**: clarity

**EDITED MORE**: to add explanation based on comment.

The double colon syntax (e.g. `Foo::getQuantity`) creates a method reference.  Double.valueOf only knows how to deal with a string.  In this case, java needs some "imperative help" to connect the dots, hence the imperative lambda, rather than the function reference.

Comment: I tried some syntax like: `Collectors.summingDouble(Double.valueOf(Foo::getQuantity))` but it didn't worked. The correct one was that one you point: `Collectors.summingDouble(foo -> Double.valueOf(foo.getQuantity()))`. Thanks!